# Getting The Array Index From string.toCharArray()

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I am making an inefficient calculator type of program that takes values from user defined arrays and plugs them into an equation that the user also defines. To do this I needed to make my program change my string to a char array, the problem? I have it so that users must use A1-10 to reference the definded index and I cannot find a way to make the program search the next array for the number to specify what array the program is accessing.

```
out.println("Please input a string of commands in a format similar to this: ");
out.println("([A1]-[A2]=) or ([A8]+[A6]=) or ([A1]-[A4]+[A7]*[A10]/[A3]=)");
out.println("Use only the numbers 1-10 when referencing an array. \n You may always type in 'Help' if you need help. ");
String eString = scn.nextLine();

if ("help".equals(eString)) {
    out.println("Figure it our yourself...");
} else {
    for (char c: eString.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == 'A') {


        }
    }
```

the code got a little jumbled up while changing code and I haven't taken the time to make it look nice and pearly again.

Comment: can you share an example containing actual numbers as to how the input looks like and how the output looks.

Comment: Your first mistake: "_I haven't taken the time to make it look nice and pearly_"

Comment: I fixed it up now... just not on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the index you should just use a normal for loop instead of an enhanced for loop.

```
char[] input = eString.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if(input[i] == 'A'){
        // You know the index of A here.
    }
}
```

You should also use `"help".equalsIgnoreCase(eString)` when comparing with help so that they can enter either `"Help"` or `"help"` ([link to doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29))

Comment: Was going to say to OP that you also need to have an `char[] array` to pick up the `String` conversion which you have named `input`. Good Job!

Comment: Dang! you guys are fast! Thanks for the help. I'll give this a try and let you know how it works out for me!

Comment: It works! Now I just gotta figure out the next step but I shouldn't need anymore help here for that. Thanks for the fast feedback!